# Can you call System.exit() in an exception class

Tags: java, exception

I have some code which calls a custom exception. However, when this exception is reached it causes my program to hang. What I want is when this exception occurs is for my program to stop running completely as this is an unrecoverable position.

So my question is: is it bad practice to call System.exit(1) in the constructor of my exception class? or should I instead call it from the code which throws the exception?

Comment: Don't handle the exception , let JVM handle it , it will automatically close I guess !!!!

Comment: _Don't handle the exception_: this is the worst suggestion i've ever seen.

Comment: No this is a custom exception I've written, the JVM doesn't care about it. The code will hang if I don't catch it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** it is a **BAD Practice** to call `System.exit(1)` in Constuctor of `Exception` Class.

In Scenario this is an **unrecoverable** `Exception`. ideally it should be a `Error` and not an `Exception`.

> Should I instead call it from the code which throws the exception?

No If its a `Exception` and only in your case you need to exit the application you should *throw* the `Exception` then *catch it* and in the `catch` block you can `exit` the application.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as my answer as this was the answer which helped me to understand and solve my problem the most. I would recommend anyone who is reading this with the same problem to read all of the answers on this page though, as they have all been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Many responses here, but let me share one more thing. ***Calling `exit` now is only a temporary*** solution. Some day, to proceed forward you will have to deal with the issue.

Recently, I was involved in an application that had native calls and the JVM would crash in one particular scenario. Doing `System.exit` temporarily worked, but unless the root cause is not solved, the application cannot be robust

So you should now look at the cause rather than the easy mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `System.exit(1)` from the code will exit the current execution of the system probably better than calling from construction.
Why are you calling `System.exit(1)` . Best is to `catch` the `exception` and make the application exit programmatically through the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code which calls a custom exception.

- You don't call an exception you just throw a exception. it good you are handling and throwing.

However, when this exception is reached it causes my program to hang.

- Something wrong with the code in your exception class too.. you got to handle that.

What I want is when this exception occurs is for my program to stop running completely as this is an unrecoverable position.

- Then you shouldn't throw custom exception, log the cause and exit.

So my question is: is it bad practice to call System.exit(1) in the constructor of my exception class? or should I instead call it from the code which throws the exception?

- see previous response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is not recommended.

because  the System.exit  method never returns normally. once a thread goes there, it won't come back.It is used to run shutdown hooks before the program quits.

IMHO Simply catch your exception and close the program.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is not caught, it should propagate all the way up the call stack until it causes the JVM to terminate the application. If that's not happening in your case, something else is wrong.

Possibility 1: As described by @rahul, if it's an unrecoverable solution, your custom "exception" should subclass `Error`. That way it will pass unhindered through all well-behaved catch blocks.

Possibility 2: The Exception is thrown in a separate thread. In that case the exception will only propagate upwards along that Thread's stack frame, which won't affect the main program by default. If you're using a framework, it should at least report that error (so you can diagnose the problem). If you create the Thread youself, you can add some proper `catch` clause (e.g. calling `System.exit()`) yourself.